# Using element.style.color within firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript function which changes text within an element, and as a bit of housecleaning also wants to ensure that the text is readable. As such, I set a white colour for dark backgrounds, or a black colour otherwise.

Now the code works as expected on IE9 and Chrome, but for some reason doesn't correctly change the color property on Firefox. Why is this? Is my way of accessing the color property not supported in Firefox?

```
function setTextContent(element, text) {
    while (element.firstChild!==null)
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild); // remove all existing content
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    if (element.style.backgroundColor == "black"
          || element.style.backgroundColor == "purple"
          || element.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
      element.style.color = "white";
    } else {
      element.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use Firebug's script debugger and put a breakpoint at your `if` statement. See what `element.style.backgroundColor` actually returns

Comment: Cheers. Firebug is a nice little tool, just grabbed it. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, it never gets to the 'appendChild' line or beyond. Which is odd. I tried adding brackets to the while loop thinking that had some effect on the debugger, but no dice. Seems odd that despite the text changing as expected that isn't shown in the debugger itself!

EDIT: Never mind, I can evaluate it with watches anyway.

Comment: If it never gets to that line, there should be an error or exception. I'd check the `Console` tab of Firebug.

Comment: You could probably replace the while loop & appendChild code with: `element.innerHTML = text;`.  But i digress, does the function get called at all (you could put an alert() in there, or use the debugger to check...)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use classes instead?

```
.blackBackground {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.purpleBackground {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}
```

...etc.

Comment: A good idea, but the colours themselves are coming from JavaScript objects elsewhere on the page. Imagine I have a bunch of Car objects, each Car has a colour, and I use the colour of the car to set the background/foreground colour for this text area.

Comment: Couldn't each Car have a background color class?

Comment: Could do, but at the moment I'm working with the objects that I have at my disposal. That's a handy thing to use in future though should I enhance the objects I am given.

Out of curiosity, how would I apply the whole contents of that class (ie background and foreground) to an element?

Comment: @f1dave Simply add that class to the element `element.className = "blackBackground"`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so the problem in the end was case-sensitivity.

"black" does not equal "Black". Should have realised that to begin with :)

Comment: Where are you comparing "white" with anything?

Comment: Well spotted, updated the explanation to reflect the code snippet used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, does `element.firstChild` ever become `null`?  Could it be set to an empty text node or something like that?

Answer (score -2):

your are checking while condition like

```
 while (element.firstChild!==null)//wrong
```

it should be like

```
   while (element.firstChild!=null)
```

or simply

```
while (element.firstChild)
```

Comment: Not quite. Have a read here http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html about the !== operator...

Comment: Using the type comparison operator is perfectly valid